# Javascript page flip effect with 1 div only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a PHP file which returns my html file content of a book (texts and images). At the top of page, i have next and prev buttons to change content of my #reader div. I need something like page flip effect to my #reader div every time user clicks prev or next buttons. Any examples do you guys can show me?

Here is my html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="toolKit">
        <p id="prev">Prev</p>
        <p id="next">Next</p>
    </div>
    <div id="reader"></div>
</div>
```

This is the JS code:

```
    var page = 1;

    $("#next").click(function () {
        if(page < 10) {
            page = page + 1;
            dataString = 'page=' + page;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ntkPageCaller.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#reader").html(response);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }});
```

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. *Most [shopping list questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) fall under this reason.*

Comment: i just need an javascript animation to show my page like its changed or flipped. I don't want you to recommend me a book, tool, or sth. Just code.

Comment: That's recommending. Coz people cannot just like that write something like this.

Comment: You mean i can't make any effect to my div with this code?

Comment: You can... There are 100s of CSS / jQuery Flip plugins available. If you are having trouble while implementing something, let us know, we'll be happy to help you.

Comment: if you are using bootstrap then take a look here....http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css3-page-flip-effect

Comment: The plugins that i found are working with multiple pages but i have only 1 div in my html to show content. Its because the books that i want to display is more than 1000 pages thats why i am calling them page by page. My system is working quite good now, i just need to make an animation to show user "my page is changed". nothing more.

Comment: You could add a fadeOut().delay().fadeIn() effect to your reader DIV, so the reader would have a visual cue that something has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a visual cue showing a change of content, then try this:

```
....
success: function (response) {
    $("#reader").fadeOut().delay(300).html(response).fadeIn();
}
```

Comment: Its working but there is a small problem. Firstly, it calls my content ( it displays on screen) and then animation comes fade out and fade in. It looks like my content is loaded twice.

Comment: You'll have to tweak it to your liking, like maybe $("#reader").hide().html(response).fadeIn();